# Windows PowerShell aliases

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using Windows PowerShell. I would like to create a short code (alias such as `jR`) for often-used commands (on my projects) such as `'gradle jR'` and so on.

What is the way to do this?

I have tried creating an alias Using `Set-Alias jR 'gradle clean jR'`, but PowerShell complains about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be confusing the use of Set-Alias. It's used to map an *existing* alias to a *different cmdlet.* To my knowledge, there is no direct way to do the kind of Linux-like mapping you wish to accomplish.

The way I do this is by having a PowerShell script called helper.ps1, which contains different *alias functions* to perform commonly-done tasks.
I then include it wherever I want to use it.

- Create a file called helper.ps1.
- Populate it with all the aliases and commonly-used functions in your project.

For example, it could contain the following function (to check the PowerShell  version)

```
Function checkPowershellVersion {
    $psversiontable.psversion.Major.ToString() + "." + $psversiontable.psversion.Minor.ToString()
    return
}
```

So for your example:

```
Function jR {
    gradle clean jR
}
```

To use the function alias, I'd simply have a `. /path/to/helper.ps1` above my PowerShell script:

```
. /path/to/helper.ps1
checkPowershellVersion
```

Comment: I don't think `. helper.ps1` will work, you must specify a path when dot-sourcing a file. e.g. `. .\helper.ps1` Of course if you use the same functions a lot you should just put them in your profile `$env:UserProfile\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1` and then you don't have to dot-source them.

Comment: OK. All I did was drop in Function jR to profile.ps1 it works a treat. Thanks guys. You both have contributed to the answer..

Answer (score -1):

```
Set-Alias -Name jR -Value "gradle clean jR"
```

Comment: This does not appear to work - on my system with PS 3.0. I believe that this kind of Linux-like ability may not be supported by PS.

Comment: This didn't work for me.. but thanks for taking time to help me :)